# I've Xamarin android application which redirects user to browser for login process. But on android 13, browser opening in split screen mode

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, multiscreen, android-13, split-screen

What i need do in order to disable browser opening in split screen mode.
Because of that user is facing login issues.

- In Android.Manifest file I've set resizeableActivity to false:

```
android:resizeableActivity="false"  here
```

I even tried putting it in activity block but didn't work.

- In MainActivity file I've also following code of line:

```
Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
```

Anyone please help me!

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: I'm facing this issue on foldable phones and on Android 13 those have large screens.